# ReactNative - NativeBase - List display as grid

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using [List](http://nativebase.io/docs/v2.0.0/components#list) from NativeBase to render data.
I have tried to setup it like this:

```
                body = <List
                    dataArray={data}
                    renderRow={(rowData) =>
                        <Person
                            key={rowData.ID}
                            searchText={searchText}
                            person={rowData}
                            onSelect={this.onSelect}
                        />}
                    onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={10}
                    contentContainerStyle={{
                        flex: 1,
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        flexWrap: 'wrap',
                        alignItems: 'flex-start'}}
                />
```

to simply display "Persons" in gird. Person is simply Card from NativeBase:

```
<Card style={{width: deviceWidth>320 ? 320 : deviceWidth,flexGrow: 1}}>
             ...
            </Card>
```

However this does not work as I expected and flexWrap is not doing anything. Everything is rendered in one row instead of wrapping into grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

Wrap the Card with a View:

```js
<View style={ styles.itemStyle} >
  <Card>
    <CardItem>
      .....
     </CardItem>
   </Card>
<View>

const styles = {
  itemStyle:
    width: 150,
    height: 100
}
```